# How can I display events from multiple source in fullcalendar?

Tags: php, fullcalendar

In fullcalendar, I want to display events from more sources, but if it has more than one event in the same time, I want just one event displayed.

Example:
Source1 : /feed1.php has event

> {type: 'souce1', start: '2013-11-22 10:30', end:'2013-11-22 11:30'}

Source2: /feed2.php has event

> {type: 'source2', start: '2013-11-22 10:30', end:'2013-11-22 11:30'}

I want just the event of source1 displayed.
Is it possible? How can I do that?